# generate multiple unique short urls?

Tags: short-url, goo.gl

Is there a way with goo.gl or a similar service to generate multiple unique short urls for a given url?

For example, if I run the following code multiple times

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
```

I always get the same short url in return

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/fbsS",
 "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"
}
```

I would like to be able to generate n diferent short urls, and to be able to get the statistics for those individual urls (that all redirect to the same site)

Thanks!

Comment: may I ask for what reasons?

Comment: Research. I'm an economist, collecting this type of data at an individual lvl would be very useful. My understanding is that marketing people do this all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a service who gives you multiple URL's, because I guess that they hash the URL and save it in a cash, so you always get the same URL. But my idea (if this is accaptable for you) would be to add some **random parameters**. So take the shortened URL and just add something like "**?v=random_string**" at the end of your id. This ways your URL is still shorter, but you have etxra parameters...

Comment: Suppose I use http://goo.gl/fbsS?v=random_1 and http://goo.gl/fbsS?v=random_2. Can I download the statistics for those two short urls? For example, I want to know the time for each click, ip, etc. Thanks!

Comment: dunno but got an better idea: Add the random strings at the URL you want to short. This way you will always get diferent short URLS which you can use ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most URL shorteners creates the same link for the same destination page in the same account. This is the reason why you cannot point multiple links to the same destination.

You need to use url shorteners that allow to create multiple links for one destination like Rebrandly (disclosure: I'm one of the founders):
https://support.rebrandly.com/hc/en-us/articles/228091508-Different-Short-Links-for-the-Same-Landing-Page

With Rebrandly you can also change the destination URL once the short link has been created and distributed: https://support.rebrandly.com/hc/en-us/articles/223449468-How-to-Change-Your-Destination-URL

Rebrandly is free and includes a great set of public API

Answer (score 0):

Try L0.CL (https://L0.CL). Put together your URLs separated with ; or in new line.

They allow 50 URLs shortening in 1 go for free.

Comment: goo.gl has stopped officially now.